What's the purpose of scanning the area before opening the portal?
In Guggenheim Museum from Spider-Man Across The Spider-Verse (2023), Miguel disarms George and traps him
in a glowing containment field:

Miguel: Lyla, scan this mess.
Lyla: No further anomalies.

Here is the scene where Lyla is shown scanning the area:

Miguel activates a PORTAL and throws Vulture into it.
What's the purpose of scanning the area before opening the portal?

I always thought “this mess” referred to the Vulture… guess I was wrong shrug (I didn’t pay attention to the scan at the time, I don’t think).

They're checking that nobody else in the vicinity is from another dimension. It's possible that when the portal opened, others came through, either of their own volition or simply because they got dragged in and they want to make sure that everyone goes back to where they started from.
We have 'anomalies' defined for us later in the script.

They web up out of frame. As our crew moves on past several dozen CONTAINMENT FIELDS, each restraining a WEIRD VARIATIONS OF A CLASSIC VILLAIN:
MILES: Who is in these...laser cages?
LYLA: Anomalies. Folks who wound up in the wrong dimension.
JESS: We kick their butts and send them home.


I believe the point is that he's trying to make sure that Vulture isn't leaving behind any persons or items that would disrupt this world before he throws him through. Imagine if, say, Vulture had left behind a clockwork minion that might keep wreaking havoc.
